# Не отображается блок в html

Tags: javascript, html, css

наткнулся на такую проблему, при создании блока с отдельным классом в вкладке он не отображается, а при создании отдельных тегов без дополнительных блоков, то все работает (посмотрите на `<div id = "tab1"> </div>`ина`<div id = "tab1"> </div>)` Строка 40 и 43 в html. Как сделать, чтобы блоки отображались?

Вот ссылка на сайт: https://jsfiddle.net/yLvwghna/

Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш блок который не показывается

```
<div id="tab1">
    <div class="miku"> Текст внутри блока с класом</div>
</div>
```

Ваш код, который должен показать блок при клике на ссылку вкладки

```
$('#tabs a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#content div").hide(); //Скрыть все сожержание
    $("#tabs li").attr("id",""); //Сброс ID
    $(this).parent().attr("id","current"); // Активируем закладку
    $('#' + $(this).attr('title')).fadeIn(); // Выводим содержание текущей закладки
});
```

эта строчка

```
$("#content div").hide();
```

скрывает ВСЕ дивы внутри #content, включая `<div class="miku"> Текст внутри блока с класом</div>`, а показываете вы потом только див `<div id="tab1">`, оставляя его содержимое скрытым

Comment: А ещё она скрывает этот `#content div` при `$(document).ready()`

Comment: Ладно, я понял суть проблемы, но если я удалю эту строчку $("#content div").hide(); ,то  контент из других вкладок будет сохраняться. Как можно допилить этот скрипт что бы контент в <div id="tab1"> не  оставался скрытым и что бы вкладки обновлялись?Помогите пожалуйста, я просто плохо знаю js)

Comment: $("#content > div").hide();